# Linux script (show user and end help)

Tags: linux, bash

I have been working on this program for some time now and I can't figure out for the life of me why this isn't working if you can help that would be great!!! please remember it is in linux.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Welcome what would you like to do? you can:"

echo "Display a list of current users (L)"

echo "Display a list of files including hidden ones (H)"

echo "Display a calender for current month (C)"

echo "Quit the program (Q)"

echo "Remember to use caps"

while read option

do

   case $option in

      L)      $ awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd ;;

      H)      ls -a ;;

      C)      cal ;;

      *)      echo "Unknown option": $option ;;

      Q)      echo "good bye" 

             ;;

    esac

done
```

Comment: And how is this not working ? Was is the expected / actual result ?

Comment: Why has this been downvoted so often -- anyone want to leave a comment why? this is a question - there are some things wrong with the script. There is an easy answer....

Comment: Upvoting. I think this is a reasonable question

Comment: Probably downvoted because ‘isn't working’ is a *really* poor description of a problem.

Comment: @Xxbat99xX One thing you should improve is that, when asking questions, and you only say "why this isn't working", please add the expected results and the actual results from your program, and describe **what** is not working. See also [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like what Andreas said: but also - parsing passwd won't tell you who is currently active on the system.

here's a modified script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Welcome what would you like to do? you can:"

echo "Display a list of all users (L)"

echo "Display a lst of current logged in users (U)"

echo "Display a list of files including hidden ones (H)"

echo "Display a calender for current month (C)"

echo "Quit the program (Q)"

echo "Remember to use caps"

while read option

do

   case $option in

      L)      awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd ;;

      U)      who ;;

      H)      ls -a ;;

      C)      cal ;;

      Q)      echo "good bye"
              exit ;;

      *)      echo "Unknown option": $option ;;

    esac

done
```

Comment: +1 for carefully reading the OPs code, where it says ""Display a list of **current** users (L)"

Comment: You might want to add the "exit" at the end of the Q) option ;) (see @Andreas answer)

Answer (score 2):

First, there is a bogus `$` sign before you are calling `awk` - use this instead:

```
...
  L)      awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd ;;
...
```

Second, you need to move the `*` case to the end of your `case` conditions, else `Q` would never be called since it is catched by `*` already.

Third, in your `Q` case, you are printing the `good bye` message, but your script will then continue to run - you need to `exit` the script:

```
 Q)      echo "good bye" 
         exit
         ;;
```

Comment: Upvoting you just because some random ***hole downvoted your perfectly reasonable answer

Comment: @TransactCharlie Thanks ;) I would really be interested in the reason for the downvote though, but these things happen from time to time ...